# Authlogic: How to prevent reuse of previous password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic, change-password

how can you find out the user's past encrypted password to check if he is using the old password as the new one, in previous "Authlogic" versions it was easy to check, but in newer versions, I cannot find out the password hash, even if I know the old salt and the new password, is there a way to determine if the user is using the old password as the new one?

Answer (score 0):

> how can you .. check if [the user] is using the old password as the new one .. I cannot find out the password hash, even if I know the old salt and the new password ..

If you have always used the same `crypto_provider`, it should be fairly simple.

```
salt = current_user.password_salt
old_crypted_pw = current_user.crypted_password
new_plaintext_password = params[:new_password]
provider = User.crypto_provider
new_crypted_pw = provider.encrypt(new_plaintext_password, salt)
if new_crypted_pw == old_crypted_pw
  raise 'Cannot reuse password'
# ...
```

Documentation of these methods can be found in `authlogic/acts_as_authentic/password.rb`.

If you are transitioning from one crypto provider to another (the `transition_from_crypto_providers` feature) then you must try to match against all `User.crypto_providers`.